# How to create 10 CSS classes, each having 10% darker gray background with LESS?

Tags: html, css, less

I'm trying to figure out the right syntax for creating 10 classes, each having darker and darker gray background colors. Output could be something like this:

```
.bg-gray-1 {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.bg-gray-2 {
  background-color: #ddd; // for example
}
...
.bg-gray-10 {
  background-color: #222; // for example
}
```

So far I've tried something like this, but prints NaNNaNNaN at the place of the colors.

```
// helper class, will never show up in resulting css
// will be called as long the index is above 0
.loop (@index) when (@index > 0) {

    // create the actual css selector
        // use (~'.@{class}_@{index}') for LESS version < 1.4
    .bg-gray-@{index} {
        background-color: darken(#eee, (@index*10)%);
    }

    // next iteration
    .loop(@index - 1);
}

// end the loop when index is 0
.loop (0) {}

.loop(10);
```

Comment: Are you using LessPHP by any chance? Put the `%` within the braces like `(@index * 10%)`.

Comment: No. Actually I'm using Visual Studio to create and compile the LESS files.

Comment: At any point are going to increase that number to 50?

Comment: No, my goal is to create 10 classes this way. It's gonna be for indicating kind of a nesting level on the UI.

Comment: Ok @ZoltánTamási. Try the option I mentioned in the first comment and it should work.

Comment: Wow, that was the point :) It works like a charm. Thank you. I made a little correction to keep the starting color first, like this: background-color: darken(#eee, (@index*10%-10%));

Comment: @Harry Please post a short answer so I can accept it and close this question

Comment: @ZoltánTamási: Sure mate, I have posted an answer. I will elaborate a bit more when I get more time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the way the percentage is being appended to the calculated number. This does not output the percentage value as a numeric percentage (like 10%, 20% etc) and hence the `darken()` function returns #NaNNaNNaN as output.

```
.bg-gray-@{index} {
    background-color: darken(#eee, (@index * 10)%);
}
```

Instead, you should add the % to the number itself and that would make Less to output the value as a percentage (instead of a string or something else).

```
.bg-gray-@{index} {
    background-color: darken(#eee, (@index * 10%));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps trying something like this, I saw it awhile back with a demo using '50 shades of gray'.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="shades">
      <div class="shade">1<span> Shades of Grey</span></div>
      <div class="shade">2<span> Shades of Grey</span></div>
      <div class="shade">3<span> Shades of Grey</span></div>
      <div class="shade">4<span> Shades of Grey</span></div>
      <div class="shade">5<span> Shades of Grey</span></div>
      <div class="shade">6<span> Shades of Grey</span></div>
      <div class="shade">7<span> Shades of Grey</span></div>
      <div class="shade">8<span> Shades of Grey</span></div>
      <div class="shade">9<span> Shades of Grey</span></div>
      <div class="shade">10<span> Shades of Grey</span></div>
</div>
```

or

**HTML (JADE)**

```
- var i = 1
.shades
  while i <= 50
   div.shade= i++
     span  Shades of Grey
```

**Normal CSS**

```
.shade {
  color: white;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 10%;
}

.shades div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
}

.shades div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #7c7c7c;
}

.shades div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: #7a7a7a;
}

.shades div:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: #787878;
}

.shades div:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-color: #767676;
}

.shades div:nth-of-type(6) {
  background-color: #747474;
}

.shades div:nth-of-type(7) {
  background-color: #727272;
}

.shades div:nth-of-type(8) {
  background-color: #707070;
}

.shades div:nth-of-type(9) {
  background-color: #6e6e6e;
}

.shades div:nth-of-type(10) {
  background-color: #6c6c6c;
}
```

or

**SASS**

```
.shade
  color: white
  padding: 50px
  text-align: center
  float: left
  margin: 5px
  font-size: 0.8em
  font-weight: bold
  width: 10%

@for $i from 1 through 50
  .shades
    div:nth-of-type(#{$i})
      background-color: darken(grey, 0.8% * $i)
```

EDIT:
Forgot the [source](http://codepen.io/gabovanlugo/pen/ByYKVV):

Comment: You've mentioned everything but Less :) I need to use Less for now, however I like the SASS approach. On the other hand, I can't use nth-child because the markup can be far more complex. That's why I needed to use classes. Thank you for your efforts anyway, can be useful for others.